# React. Не обновляется компонент после обновления useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hook, usestate

Есть приложение на React, в котором 2 страницы. Первая страница запускает видео файл на весь экран. Вторая страница должна управлять первой (менять видео).

На второй странице создаю:

```html
<input type="file">
```

получаю с помощью FileReader и передаю видео из input в родительский компонент (App.jsx) сохраняя в setCurrentVideo. После этого currentVideo отправляю из App.jsx на первую страницу...
В App.jsx файл приходит, console.log(currentVideo) показывает, что файл на месте, НО на первой странице не меняется видео.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Нужно чтобы после добавления видео в input на второй странице, первая страница автоматически запускала новое видео (без звука).

```js
function App() {

  const [currentVideo, setCurrentVideo] = useState();

  console.log(currentVideo) // показывает, что файл на месте...

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<VideoPage currentVideo={currentVideo}/>}/>
        <Route path='/admin' element={<AdminPage setCurrentVideo={setCurrentVideo}/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```js
function VideoPage({ currentVideo }) {

    return(
        <div className="video-box">
            <video className='video' src={currentVideo} autoPlay loop preload="auto" muted></video>
        </div>
    )
}
export default VideoPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

В компоненте `AdminPage` нужно добавить функцию

Функция будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const files = e.target.files;
  if (files) {
    setCurrentVideo(URL.createObjectURL(Array.from(files)[0]));
  }
};
```

Функцию onChangeHandler необходимо передать инпуту. Следующим образом

```
<input type="file" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
```

Если будут вопросы, то задавайте. Удачи!